# python-daemon installation fails when using --prefix

Tags: python, jenkins, airflow

if I execute:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=/root/folder" airflow==1.8.0
```

it will end so

```
    'dist_version': self.distribution.get_version(),
  File "version.py", line 656, in get_version
    version_info = self.get_version_info()
  File "version.py", line 651, in get_version_info
    changelog_path = get_changelog_path(self)
  File "version.py", line 552, in get_changelog_path
    setup_dirname = os.path.dirname(distribution.script_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 129, in dirname
    i = p.rfind('/') + 1
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

If I execute

```
 pip install airflow==1.8.0
```

it will complete the process with no errors.

```
# pip freeze 
airflow==1.8.0
alembic==0.8.10
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
chardet==2.2.1
click==6.7
croniter==0.3.16
dill==0.2.6
docutils==0.13.1
Flask==0.11.1
Flask-Admin==1.4.1
Flask-Cache==0.13.1
Flask-Login==0.2.11
flask-swagger==0.2.13
Flask-WTF==0.12
funcsigs==1.0.0
future==0.15.2
gitdb2==2.0.0
GitPython==2.1.3
gunicorn==19.3.0
iniparse==0.4
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8.1
kitchen==1.1.1
lockfile==0.12.2
lxml==3.7.3
Mako==1.0.6
Markdown==2.6.8
MarkupSafe==1.0
numpy==1.12.1
ordereddict==1.1
pandas==0.19.2
psutil==4.4.2
pycurl==7.19.0
Pygments==2.2.0
pygobject==3.14.0
pygpgme==0.3
pyliblzma==0.5.3
python-daemon==2.1.2
python-dateutil==2.6.0
python-editor==1.0.3
python-nvd3==0.14.2
python-slugify==1.1.4
pytz==2017.2
pyxattr==0.5.1
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.13.0
setproctitle==1.1.10
six==1.10.0
smmap2==2.0.1
SQLAlchemy==1.1.8
tabulate==0.7.7
thrift==0.9.3
Unidecode==0.4.20
urlgrabber==3.10
Werkzeug==0.12.1
WTForms==2.1
yum-metadata-parser==1.1.4
zope.deprecation==4.2.0
```

Since this has to run into a jenkins build process, I can't omit the install option. Can any power python-user help me to understand where to see and how to fix it ?

I read that you need to install this library (python-daemon) before anything else, but still does not work using the install options:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=/root/folder" python-daemon 

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py:188: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options / --global-options / --install-options.
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 230, in finalize_options
        'dist_version': self.distribution.get_version(),
      File "version.py", line 656, in get_version
        version_info = self.get_version_info()
      File "version.py", line 651, in get_version_info
        changelog_path = get_changelog_path(self)
      File "version.py", line 552, in get_changelog_path
        setup_dirname = os.path.dirname(distribution.script_name)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 129, in dirname
        i = p.rfind('/') + 1
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

python-daemon requires docutils.

```
pip install docutils
```

After that run

```
pip install python-daemon
```

Comment: how you are sure about it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get it working, not the best and not the final solution, but it's working:

```
 pip install python-daemon
```

when it completes you should be able to see it into the list of

```
[root@localhost ozw1z5rd]# pip freeze | grep daemon 
python-daemon==2.1.2
```

now uninstall it

```
 pip uninstall python-daemon
```

and of course it will not longer available into the list of

```
[root@localhost ozw1z5rd]# pip freeze | grep daemon
```

now install again using the prefix

```
 pip install --install-option="--prefix=/root/folder" python-daemon
```

this installation, of course, it is not available into the pip freeze list, but it completes with no error and inside the new path the library does exist.

```
[root@localhost ozw1z5rd]# ls /root/folder/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
daemon/                             python_daemon-2.1.2-py2.7.egg-info/
```

All this allowed me to install airflow using Jenkins.

I investigated also the setup.py script of python-daemon, attrs['script_name'] is correctly loaded in the early part of the code, but it get lost later.

[image]

In this screen the code shown is where the attrs['script_name'] get lost.